# write Rhino Mock Test cases for Web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3, rhino-mocks

HI  have created a WEBAPI below. i am trying to write rhino Mocks for below API i have tried a lot but everytime i failed

**WEBAPI Client to hit web api**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestAPI(string test)
    {

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:42327/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Home/test/test").Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                ViewBag.Valid = result;
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                ViewBag.Valid = result;
                return View();
            }
        }
    }

**WEBAPI Code**


    [Route("api/{Home}/{Username}/{Password}")]
            public HttpResponseMessage Get(string Username, string Password)

            {
                HttpResponseMessage response;
                var display = Userloginvalues().Where(m => m.UserName == Username && m.Password == Password).FirstOrDefault();
                if (display != null)
                {
                    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                    response.Content = new StringContent("xxxx.", Encoding.Unicode);
                }
                else
                {
                    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
                    response.Content = new StringContent("xxxx", Encoding.Unicode);
                }
                return response;

            }
            public static List<LoginModel> Userloginvalues()
            {
                List<LoginModel> objModel = new List<LoginModel>();
                objModel.Add(new LoginModel { UserName = "test", Password = "test" });
                return objModel;
            }
```

RHIN MOCKS i tried below but dont know how to proceed

```
            MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();

            HttpResponseMessage _respone;
            _respone = login.Get("test", "test");
```

Comment: Show the unit test. You controller code shows you creating a response from a request, but you mock setup does not show you creating any requests.

Comment: For brief i am hitting the Get from client and reading the response of Web api....@Nkosi above code is api controller code..i simply want to write rhino mock for GET method i.e having params username and password....i am not able to write for  mentioned route....please let me know if anything now required from my side

Comment: Your code shows `ILoginRepository.Get` which would be different to your Controller's `Get`. Your explanation is still not clear.

Comment: sorry for that i am not using "ILoginRepository" this interafce now....

Comment: @Nkosi just updated my code client and webapi...now i want to test webapi using rhino mock..now explanation is clear enough???

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the Help Center.

Comment: @Nkosi thanks i knew that if you have any  sort of answer if you  understood 1 % please..what you are not getting from above that i don't understand?????

Comment: Is this a unit test or an integration test? Your code indicates that you are trying to *unit test* an MVC Controller (your client) making a http request to a WebAPI. It is difficult to ascertain which is the system or method under test in your scenario.  You have not shown how you setup the test so that one can see what may be causing your problem. Is the web api running at the time of the test?